# Collision detection for 2D (convex) polygons given vertices of the polygons

Tags: c#, algorithm, collision-detection, polygon

I am given a list of 2D coordinate points which are the vertices of a polygon. I should place randomly created polygons on this polygon board in a way that they should not collide with each other.

As the lower and upper bounds of my random function, I find a bounding rectangular box for my given points. (I just find this to specify the boundary of random generator function.)

Here, I assume all the random polygons are rectangles. Then I randomly create 8 points at each step, which represent the vertices of a rectangle:
(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4)

Now to know whether:

1. rectangles are inside of the polygon board,
2. rectangles are not colliding with previously placed rectangles,

I want to use the **collision detection algorithm**, which is based on the *Separating Axis Theorem* and is explained [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20141127210836/http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Polygon_Collision).

```
var rand = new Random();

var numbers = new List<int>(); // A sample of one of the rectangles

numbers.Add(rand.Next(0, 100)); // x1
numbers.Add(rand.Next(0, 100)); // y1
numbers.Add(numbers[0] + rand.Next(1, 10)); //x3
numbers.Add(numbers[1] + rand.Next(1, 10)); //y3
numbers.Add(numbers[0]); // x4
numbers.Add(numbers[3]); // y4
numbers.Add(numbers[2]); // x2
numbers.Add(numbers[1]); // y2


var numbers2 = new List<int>(); // We assume that this is the given
//original polygon board

numbers2.Add(rand.Next(70, 200)); // x1
numbers2.Add(rand.Next(70, 200)); // y1
numbers2.Add(numbers2[0] + rand.Next(1, 10)); //x3
numbers2.Add(numbers2[1] + rand.Next(1, 10)); //y3
numbers2.Add(numbers2[0]); // x4
numbers2.Add(numbers2[3]); // y4
numbers2.Add(numbers2[2]); // x2
numbers2.Add(numbers2[1]); // y2
```

For now, let's forget about looping through previously placed rectangles and checking with them. I just want to know:

1. How can I define a connecting line between every two 2D points (which represents a side of a rectangle) and then find a perpendicular line to it? (I'm in a console application).

   > point1 = (x1, y1), point2 = (x2, y2) and so on. Also, point1 should be
   >   connected to point2, point2 to point3 and so on, and the last one to
   >   the point1 again.
2. How can I project all the points of every side of each rectangle on the perpendicular line?
3. Or if there is a totally different way to solve this problem which would be easier :)